# Why does adding an attribute prevent categories from expanding?

Tags: adminform

This code will add a dropdown just fine, but now I can't expand the category tree.  Any ideas why this would happen?

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'review_enabled',  array(
'input'    => 'select',
'required' => true,
'label'    => 'Review Enabled?',
'option'            => array ('value' => array(
    'optionone' => array('Yes'),
    'optiontwo' => array('No'))),
'global'   => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
'group'    => 'Featured Review'));
```

I'm seeing this error in the console when I click on "expand" icon next to categories:

```
prototype.js:1530 POST http://<<mySite>>/catalog_category/categoriesJson/?isAjax=true 503 (Service Unavailable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it does have to do with the type of input you add.   Do not include "checkbox" or "textarea", both of which I was trying to add.  I don't know *why* those types aren't there or how to add them, but this is what broke category tree.

These are the only types that Magento ships with, apparently.

[image: Magento's catalog_category_entity entries]